# Browser Link Save Changes to SASS files from browser

Tags: css, visual-studio-2015, sass, browser-link

Is it possible to save css changes that I do in Chrome to the correct places in my sass file in Visual Studio 2015?

I cannot find any information on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Browser/code sync is available on localhost using Web Essentials 2015. I know that it syncs directly to your compiled .css file, but I hardly ever use that feature, so I do not know if it can be configured to write to your sass file. I would kind of be surprised if you found anything just because  it would be extremely difficult to reverse map your css file back into the sass version simply because of the nature of sass code with nested rules, mixins, extends, variables, etc.